# Insert values starting from first row of a column in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my first post here. I am new to sqlite and relatively new to Python programming itself! So, sorry if my question is dumb! :)

I am trying to store some values in sqlite database columns iteratively which will be later used to make new columns and keep the code running.

My problem is that, when a new column is made, writing values into it doesn't start from the first row of the new column but from after the last row of the previous column. Lets say if the previous column was 100 rows long, writing values in the column that is newly made starts from row 101.

Here is a part of the code that I am using:

```
 ...some lines....

 iter=1  # counter for the iteration number which will be used in naming the columns and accessing them

...blah blah

cur.execute("alter table C add column stress_IP1_%d"%iter) #makes a new column named by iteration number
for e in range(0,numel): 
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO C (stress_IP1_%d) VALUES (?)"%iter, (w[e],)) #writes values of W (list) into column made above. 
con.commit()
```

I greatly appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` is for adding new row. You probably need `UPDATE` to change values in existing row.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried the following, but it fills the whole column with the last value of my counter (here 12) instead of filling the column from 2 to 12.Where am I making a mistake? I tried both putting the commit inside and outside the for loop:
     blah blah
     iter=19
     blah blah
     for kk in range (2,13):
        cur.execute("UPDATE C SET column_%d=?"%iter, (kk,))    
     con.commit()

Comment: Use `WHERE` in `UPDATE`